# Android studio 1.0 AVD not launching

Tags: android, android-studio

Just started using Android Studio 1.0 stable release. But, whenever I launch an AVD, It is not getting launched.

Am getting the following under Run Log tab:

```
C:\Users\Badhrinath\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_21
```

Also am not getting any errors displayed.

I am using `GenyMotion` now, but just want to know what's the issue as it went well even in Beta version.

Comment: Which sdk version are you using?

Comment: @Badhrinath Canessane hope my solution help to you . let me know if it work or not .

Answer (score 1):

Other issue :
   Sometime launch ADV from ADV manager doesn't launch ADV and nothing happen as your issue .

Solution :
Don't launch ADV from ADV manager , just run your project and in pop up windows u should select whether phone or emulator run your project , you select emulator to run your  and ADV should come up . And sometime delete and create new device will fix some issue .

Answer (score 0):

Android studio version 1.0 . ADV "failed to load" Error

See  Issue 81552 I asked :https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=81552

Workaround

simply copy Android Studio folder from where u installed assumption : "c:\program
   file\android"  to same location as your SDK Location .

I tested it and this should work for now : thanks to great studio project member "romin"

[image: this image token after i moved studio to mentioned location]

[image: emulator runing now after the solution in my machine and sure it is great looking now]

Answer (score 0):

I found sometimes it gets blocked by anti-virus software, so try disabling that.